# In Update view, the dropdown selected value is not set if the selected field is nullable in viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

Say for example my viewmodel is as follows:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int? SelectedCategoryId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; } 
}
```

And the view is as follows:

```
 @model MyViewModel

    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.SelectedCategoryId,
        Model.Categories,
        "--Select--"
    )
```

In the update view, if the model has a value for the SelectedCategoryId it is not shown selected in the dropdownlist. The "--Select--" is always selected. The same logic works for other dropdownlist if their Id field are not nullable.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So even if there is a value in SelectedCategoryID it is just showing "--Select--"?

Comment: Yes, even if the SelectedCategoryID has a value it shows "--Select--".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used jquery to select the dropdown if the Id has a value.

In the view, I create a hidden field (don't use the @Html.HiddenFor)

```
 @Html.Hidden("SelectedCategorySubId", Model.SelectedCategorySubId.GetValueOrDefault(), new { @id = "hdnSelectedCategorySubId" })
```

In JS file,in the call back method of ajax call (to load the drop down),after adding data to dropdown, get the hidden field value and then select that value in dropdown.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "GetSubCategory",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(param),
            success: function (subCategoryList) {

                if (subCategoryList != null && subCategoryList != '') {

                    $("#SelectedCategorySubId").append('<option>--- Select ---</option>');
                    $.each(subCategoryList, function (i, subCategory) {

                        $("#SelectedCategorySubId").append($('<option/>', {
                            value: subCategory.Value,
                            text: subCategory.Text
                        }));
                    });

                 //Set selected value from hidden field
                    var selectedCategorySubId = $("#hdnSelectedCategorySubId").val();
                  // alert("Sub Cat" + selectedCategorySubId);
                    $("#SelectedCategorySubId").val(selectedCategorySubId);

                }//end if
                else {
                    //alert("empty subcategoryList " + subCategoryList);
                    $("#tdSubCategory").hide();

                }
            }
```

And update the hidden field if the dropdown changes

```
//Update hidden field, if cat changes
$("#SelectedCategorySubId").change(function () {
    $("#hdnSelectedCategorySubId").val($(this).val());
});
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting you a simple approach.
If you are using `IEnumerable <SelectListItem>` then there is no need to user different variable for Maintaining Selected value.. Just mark your category selected when you are populating `Categories` SelectList.

```
SelectListItem category = new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "CategoryId",
                Value = "CatagoryName",
                Selected = true
            };

Categories.Add(category);

public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; } 
}
```

..............................................

@model MyViewModel

```
@Html.DropDownList("Name",
    Model.Categories,
    "--Select--"
)
```

Comment: I can't change the model. I have to use the nullable field to save the selected field. Thanks for your suggestion.